# Focused element after mvc client validation fail seems arbitrary

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using mvc unobtrusive validation. And when I press my submitbutton I get a client side validation fail and one of my failed textbox elements get focused. If I then press the button once again another element get focused.

What determines what element gets focused after a validation fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i solved my problem like this: 
Please feel free to comment and if you have a better answer please tell.

For css issues I had to first select all of the invalid inpus before I selected the top one. (For some reason the css partly acted like the top one was not focused if i just selected the first one without first selecting them one by one :/ )

```
$('.input-validation-error').each(function () {
            this.focus();
        });

       var inp = $('.input-validation-error:first').get(0);

        if (inp) {
            inp.focus();
        }
```